# Regex match up to last line that starts with `- [`

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, substring

I have a designated chunk of a body that contains a GitHub Markdown list formatted like so:

```
**HEADERONE**
- [x] Logged In
- [ ] Logged Out
- [x] Spun Around
- [x] Did the hokey pokey
```

But that list is surrounded by other junk like this:

```
A body paragraph about other things. Lorem ipsom and all that

**HEADERONE**
- [x] Logged In
- [ ] Logged Out
- [x] Spun Around
- [x] Did the hokey pokey

Maybe a link here www.go_ogle.com 

Another list that isn't important
- [ ] Thing one
- [ ] Thing two
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
```

I can chop the string programmatically after grabbing, but I was curious if there was a very clean way to grab just my list? The header is always identical, so grabbing from `**HEADERONE**` until the first instance of a double new line would work fine. Grabbing from `**HEADERONE**` until the end of the last line with `- [` would be amazing though.

I was using

```regex
\*\*HEADERONE\*\*[^*]*?(?=\n{2})
```

but while that works in regex101, `re.search("\*\*HEADERONE\*\*[^*]*?(?=\n{2})",body)` returns none for some reason.
So I switched it to

```regex
\*\*HEADERONE\*\*[\S\s]*?(?=\n{2})
```

but that grabs too much, including the second list. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there CRLF endings? Try replacing `(?=\n{2})` with `(?=(?:\r\n){2})`. An alternative can be [`(?m)^\*\*HEADERONE\*\*(?:\r?\n-\s*\[[^][]*].*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/5VdQqt/1)

Comment: Try `(?m)\*\*HEADERONE\*\*(?:\s+^- +\[.*)+`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/A8gahu/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew replacing `(?=\n{2})` with `(?=(?:\r\n){2})` worked perfectly! Though it stopped working on regex101, it works great in python3. If you can put an answer explaining why or what that second string does differently I'll mark as accepted!

Comment: I also added a non-regex approach for getting all matching occurrences in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although replacing `(?=\n{2})` with `(?=(?:\r\n){2})` will fix the problem since you have CRLF endings in the input, I'd suggest a more precise pattern:

```
m = re.search(r'^\*\*HEADERONE\*\*(?:\r?\n-\s*\[[^][]*].*)*', s, re.M)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5VdQqt/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ickIuN).

**Explanation**

- `^` - start of a line (`re.M` redefines the `^` anchor behavior)
- `\*\*HEADERONE\*\*` - a `**HEADERONE**` string
- `(?:\r?\n-\s*\[[^][]*].*)*` - zero or more consecutive repetitions of

  - `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF only ending
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\[` - a `[` char
  - `[^][]*` - 0+ chars other than `]` and `[`
  - `]` - a `]`
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

Also, there is a way to grab all the matches in the file using non-regex approach:

```
res = []
tmp = []
inblock = False
for line in f:  # f is a handle to the open file, or use s.splitlines() to split the string s into lines
    if line == '**HEADERONE**':
        tmp.append(line.rstrip())
        inblock = not inblock
    elif inblock and line.startswith("- ["):
        tmp.append(line.rstrip())
    else:
        if len(tmp) > 0:
            res.append("\n".join(tmp))
            tmp = []
            inblock = not inblock
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/ls5UKI). Basically, once the `**HEADERONE**` is found, all subsequent lines starting with `- [` are appended to `tmp`, and then joined into an item in the `res` list.

Comment: Great answer. Consider using `s.splitlines()` vs `s.split('\n')`. `s.split('\n')` gets confused with `\r\n` line endings where `s.splitlines()` applies universally. You might be able to loose the `.rstrip()` if you don't care about trailing whitespace in that case.

Comment: @dawg I see, that is a good thing to keep in mind, however, the `s.split('\n')` should actually be a handle to the open file, I changed the code snippet. Well, if that is a string and not a file, that is much better.

Comment: Yes -- I agree with what you say regarding a file. The `\r\n` vs `\n` can then be handled with [Universal Line Support](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) by adding `U` to the file open mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can find everything between `\*\*HEADERONE\*\*` and the first blank line with the following:

```
^(\*\*HEADERONE\*\*[\s\S]*?)^\s*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VahJam/1/)

The `[\s\S]*?` matches all characters, including newlines, up to the first blank line. If there is a possibility that there is no blank line or the end of the string, you can add that test easily to the form:

```
^(\*\*HEADERONE\*\*[\s\S]*?)(?:^\s*$|\Z)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VahJam/2/)

---

If you want to have a Python non-regex way to get that block, and the blocks are separated by two or more new lines, you can do:

```
print('\n'.join(block for block in s.replace('\r\n', '\n').split('\n\n') if block.lstrip().startswith('**HEADERONE**')))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VZI9bxsxDIZ3/QpuZxvuLZ07GIiBFmgboB9TUxTyibljLZGKRNXxr3ep2AiQRdArvqQeUspnXYTfXy71wzAMD24HBwlnyL74ufi8gD9IUxBdsIAuxHMd4bMUTEC5SgLPAXyMFvPq3Gbzcb@723@7/7rfbNw7@PX829zzjAE@cdfwqu@b3gzfc2PYFWkcbid3FKwgwiJHNJi@OvfFnw8IHiLxEQwH4XQ6jbP8kTniOBmLczu@kkaq@oIEVHmwNWUp6llvDD96JyCMb7SexL321hIEiVKgkoJPqFuYhCtOitoK@ECZ6tTTMJIFq/UUBJBaTWL42K8E4okChcYKNsZo0zRu1GtphORn9jY/emp@hJ8KyGQzDZCob/6Z9GkLT40qsFQtLQA@Y5lIvZIwtBh9muRauZuoUr/ppSRlMwN6A0/GJAD2xs7lQqyr4YGH8a8Qrw5RpiM8Gu11Rwx1LJijn9BsxYxb6Pb1WLP12lO7Anq8ZozRyCivLK6@aD2RLqvhzV8Y1uv15fIf)

Or, if you have a file:

```
print('\n'.join(block for block in fo.read() if block.lstrip().startswith('**HEADERONE**')))
```

Where `fo` is a file opened with `'U'` in the file mode.

Answer (score 2):

```
regex = r'\*\*HEADERONE\*\*(?:\n.+)+'
#^^^ HEADER followed by ONE newline and some other stuff
results = re.findall(regex, text)
print(results[0])
#**HEADERONE**
#- [x] Logged In
#- [ ] Logged Out
#- [x] Spun Around
#- [x] Did the hokey pokey
```